# Is there a principled reason behind differing compound verb stress in English?

Tags: english, phonology, verbs, stress, compounds

Is there a principled difference between compound verbs in English with stress on the first root and those with stress on the second root?

First root stress compound verbs:

- Dropkick
- Spoonfeed
- Babysit
- Whitewash
- Break dance

Second root stress compound verbs:

- Understand
- Overflow
- Double-click

Also, are there any disyllabic compound words in English with stress on the second root?

Sources: "Contemporary Linguistics" O'Grady et al., https://socratic.org/questions/what-is-a-compound-verb-and-some-examples, https://www.englishclub.com/pronunciation/word-stress-rules.htm